# Can I use SignalR 2.2 in an ASP5 vNext (beta8) application?

Tags: asp.net, signalr, asp.net-core

According to the ASP.Net 5 Roadmap, SignalR 3 won't make it into the RTM. https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap

Is it possibly to use SignalR 2.2 in a vNext project? How do I call `MapSignalR()`? The Configure method in Startup.cs has an IApplicationBuilder, but the extension method for SignalR wants to be called on IAppBuilder, is it possibly to have a second Startup class? How would I go about setting that up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of RC1, see [IAppBuilderBridge sample](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/dev/samples/Owin.IAppBuilderBridge) to get SignalR 2.2 working on RC1. You just grab the `KatanaIApplicationBuilderExtensions` class from that project and then add signalR to the `Startup` class this way:

```
app.UseAppBuilder(
  appBuilder =>
  {
      appBuilder.MapSignalR();
  });
```

I added it after `UseMvc`.

Just tested myself on a clean new MVC project on RC1 and under IIS Express. At least the [Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc) sample works just fine. And as Todd Sprang pointed in a comment, it should work because it does not depend on higher level ASP.NET components very much.

See also [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/11/14/katana-asp-net-5-and-bridging-the-gap/).

Answer (score 0):

Just create this class in your App_Start folder, and modify to taste.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRStartup))]

namespace Comp.Prod.Web
{
    public class SignalRStartup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            try
            {
                var hubConfig = new HubConfiguration
                {
#if DEBUG
                    EnableDetailedErrors = true
#else
                EnableDetailedErrors = false
#endif
                };

                GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseSqlServer(Settings.Default.BackplaneConnectionString);

                app.MapSignalR(hubConfig);

                GlobalHost.HubPipeline.RequireAuthentication();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Following exception thrown from SignalRStartup:");
                Debug.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc

Comment: This didn't work. The Configuration method in SignalRStartup is never called. I also tried adding the method to the Startup.cs file that is created by default, and it doesn't get called there either. The tutorial you linked is for MVC5, but vNext projects use MVC6.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're starting from. If you follow those directions (use a simpler startup than mine) they should just work as well for 6 as 5, though I haven't tried 6 personally. SignalR is an independent technology from ASP.NET and will continue to work alongside it.